# ssh X11 fowarding doesn't work: Error: cannot open display: :5

Tags: centos, ssh, xforwarding

I have connected my Workstation (Windows PC) via ssh with X11forwarding to a remote PC(CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 ). 
The ssh connection works fine, but when I' try to open firefox or some other GUI I get the following error message: `Error: cannot open display: :5`. 
I also checked the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file if X11Forwarding is enabled and it is. 
I am using MobaXterm to establish a ssh connection, but i also tried putty or open ssh (ssh -Y user@rempte-adress) with the same result. `echo $DISPLAY` shows :5. Does anyone have any idea what's the problem is here?

**EDIT**

if I try to start the X server with `startx` i get the following error message

```
xauth:  file /home/glock/.serverauth.23745 does not exist

(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
        Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
^Cxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: Have you any running X11 server with active display?

Comment: Did you install xauth?

Comment: xauth is installed, but i think the X Server doesn't run. In my Question above u can see the output if i try to start the X Server.

Comment: Do you have a X server running on your Windows machine? You should not be trying to start X on the Linux machine over SSH

Comment: The error "cannot open display: :5" suggests the DISPLAY variable is correctky set on centos side (which you still can check with 'echo $DISPLAY'), and xorg-x11-xauth rpm should be there. This means the issue may be on your PC: what X server are you running there? Xming? cygwin/X ? Some permission missing (xhost like ?)

Comment: Yes on my Windows machine a X Server is running, i can use X11 forwarding on other remote PC with no Problems, it only doesn't work on that specific remote PC i talked of at my first statement.

Comment: I tried to check with NetCat if the port 6010 is open on the remote pc and i get a timedout, could this be the problem? Port 22 is open

Comment: i had to change my display variable to localhost:10 and then use another xserver in this case xming then it worked out, only changing the xserver didn't helped